# PDO Insert 300.000 Rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a json file and i want to insert all data to my database.

First i am trying to get contents from json file and store in array. It takes 20 seconds.

```
$strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents('C:\books.json');
$array = json_decode($strJsonFileContents);
```

After that i prepare the insert query

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO product SET
webID = ?,
name = ?,
subtitle = ?,
title = ?,
description = ?,
ISBN = ?
.
.
.
");
```

I create a foreach loop and execute insert query.

```
foreach($array->Books as $book){
    $insert = $query->execute(array(
    $book->p2,
    $book->p3,
    $book->p4
    .
    .
    .
));
```

This foreach loops has 300.000 loop. It takes huge time to insert. - I didn't see finish, it made 40,000 additions in about 10 minutes.

What should I do to reduce this time to seconds? It is not a big problem for me to have 20 seconds to read from the file but inserting time it is a huge problem.

Comment: Are you using innoDB ? if so change it to myisam, use transaction() and end with commit.

Comment: @OSentrk: don't listen anyone who suggests INSERT INTO solutions. Google LOAD DATA INFILE, this way is x100 times faster.

Comment: convert the json file to csv and use LOCAL INFILE, that is much less programming effort.

Comment: Use transactions to speed it up.

Comment: as @user1597430 said, consider using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, it's the best way to make mass insert in database. But you will have to convert you json file into csv file. At least you will save lots of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce this is to create one query using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`webID`, `name`, `subtitle`, `title`, `description`, `ISBN`)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?) .... // and so on
```

Using the PHP to assemble the `VALUES` portion of the query as you can have multiple sets of these. Then run the query ONE time.

Regardless of how you do this, it will take some time to prepare the query and then execute it. Inserting that many rows at once is not trivial.